# Homomorphic encryption with Ethereum compatible chains

Tags: encryption

Are there any blockchains or even Ethereum mainnet contracts that would offer homomorphic encryption primitives and example code?

A sample use case would be [homomorphic secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_secret_sharing) that is needed for a secret ballot voting.

Comment: It might be worth elaborating a bit about what *homomorphic encryption* is.

Comment: Assuming if someone knows the answer they are familiar with the term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption

Comment: Side note: doing it on a public (or any blockchain that you do not have free usage) would be a bad idea, due to possible high amount of required gas.